Django App is delayed or does not reflect the changes in the new code
We have a django app deployed to AWS EC2 instances (autoscaled) via codedeploy.
The deployment is successful, and I can see the new code when connected to the instances.
However, the django app did not reflect the changes in the new code. Why is that?
We also had a case when we did a database migration and the new fields only showed up 1 day later.
WE foudn the DNS Time-To-Live (TTL) value is set to 2 days by default, which we have now updated it to a shorter timeframe. However, it hasn't made any progress.
Have also restarted the servers etc.

If on server restart, changes are still not reflected, then the issue isn’t with Django.
